# Multiple Text change animation not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've been looking further into animation lately, and wanted to animate a text that transitions from one word, to another word, to another word, etc. and while the code im using does do what its supposed to, there's a frame in between where you see the text changing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Attempted adding more keyframes making it more like a steplike code, but this didn't seem to work.

**HTML** (where the text changes):

```
<h2 class="subtitle">I am feeling <b class="moods"></b></h2>
```

**CSS**

```
.moods:before {
    content: 'sad';
    animation-name: head;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes head {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    5% {opacity:1; content: "sad";  }
    10% {opacity:0;}
    15% {opacity:1; content: "happy"; }
    20% {opacity:0; }
    25% {opacity:1; content: "joyfull"}
    30% {opacity:0;}
    35% {opacity:1; content: "mad"}
    40% {opacity:0; }
    45% {opacity:1; content: "depressed"}
    50% {opacity:0; }
    55% {opacity:1; content: "angry"}
    60% {opacity:0; }
    65% {opacity:1; content: "twitchy"}
    70% {opacity:0; }
    75% {opacity:1; content: "sick"}
    80% {opacity:0; }
    85% {opacity:1; content: "healthy"}
    90% {opacity:0; }
    95% {opacity:1; content: "energetic"}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}
```

I like the way it's working already, I'd just like it to be a smooth transition without seeing the word change when it changes the content of the class.

Answer (score 0):

We can make things a little more interesting by chaining our transitions together using commas, then playing with the duration and delay of them to create the same sort of multi-step movement effect that is possible in keyframe animation.